# How to take screenshot of a Gnome application without the transparent CSD border?

Tags: gnome, xfce, csd

I’m on Xfce. I don’t want the transparent border coming from Gnome’s client-side decoration. How can I achieve this?

[image: screenshot with transparent CSD border]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling Xfce's compositor fixes the problem.
[image]

Comment: Great answer, but please add details - how and where compositor was disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ubuntus default gnome-screenshot gui (power key, type 'screenshot'), then click select area to grab, and highlight the window and not the borders. you might also try running it from the command line with remove borders (I have not tried this myself)

```
gnome-screenshot -B -w
```

to select the area with mouse drag

```
gnome-screenshot -B -w
```

gnome-screenshot --help for more info.